# How to extract data from a table and summarise in a text string based on certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I think I can explain my question the best using a picture:
[My example and problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ7do.png)

Basically I need a formula, that concatenates the rows "Client" and then the percentage for that Client and the monthly date so many times how often the "Name1" appears in the table.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Right... tricky but can be done!

**Data tables**

First things first, familiarise yourself with Excel's "Data Table" feature found under the Data ribbon > What-if Analysis. The data table allow you to create a 2D variable table, of which the header column (x) and header row (y) are substituted into a formula, e.g. like this for calculation of a circle's radius:

[image]

**The plan**

We will create a data table, with the names as column input values and the dates as row input values. Those values will be substituted into a formula that calculates the summary text, mathematically speaking F(x,y) = SUMMARY(name, date).

We will add two columns to your original data called "Selected date" and "Summary for selected name". Also name cells off to the side called Input *date* and *name*. Give those cells any valid value for the moment (e.g. name1 and 21-Feb). The data table will substitute values into these cells and "copy" the calculated summary text into the table.

[image]

**The summary formula**

Now implement the following formula:

[image]

Its important to have the blank ="" cell in F2, as its the starting point for the summary text that gets propagated row by row.

The selected date column E just duplicates the % data for the selected *date*. HLOOKUP looks up the column by *date* in the header row and returns the current row's value with ROW().

```
=HLOOKUP(date, $C$1:$D$5, ROW(), TRUE)
```

The summary column F uses IF(...) to determine if the selected *name* matches the current row, then concatenates the client's name and % value (from column E) onto the summary string above it. If the names doesn't match, if simply brings the current summary string down from above.

```
=IF($A3=name, F2 & $B3 & "(" & E3*100 & "%), ", F2)
```

Lastly, the total for the selected person is concatenated to the summary text using SUMIF in F6 (to only add the % data if it belongs to the currently selected person):

=F5 & "Sum (" & SUMIF($A$3:$A$5, name, C3:C5)*100 & "%)"

Lastly and most NB! The corner cell of the data table A8 must reference our summary cell =F6. Type the list of unique names in the data table A9:A10 and duplicate the dates in row 8. Select the whole data table area A8:C10, click Data > What-if Analysis > Data table and set the row input by selecting the cell named *data* and set the column input by selecting the cell named *name*.

Comment: Ps. to drop 0% from the summary text, modify the formula =IF(AND($A3=name, E3>0), F2 & $B3 & "(" & E3*100 & "%), ", F2)

Answer (score 1):

In `J3`, array formula (CSE) copied right to `K3` and all copied down :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(($C$4:$C$6=$I3)*(INDEX($E$4:$F$6,,MATCH(J$2,$E$3:$F$3,0))<>0),$D$4:$D$6&TEXT(INDEX($E$4:$F$6,,MATCH(J$2,$E$3:$F$3,0))," (0%);;;"),""),"Sum"&TEXT(SUMIFS(INDEX($E$4:$F$6,,MATCH(J$2,$E$3:$F$3,0)),$C$4:$C$6,$I3)," (0%);;;"))
```

[image]

Comment: Boss mode activated!

Answer (score 0):

Oh and I'm of course assuming you **really** do need the text summary, otherwise the pivot table is your best friend:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I did it with the pivot table! ;)

Comment: LOL yes... uhm well sometimes the best solution is just the simplest solution. Do check mark the solution so others can see the problem has been solved.